# How to manange two different codeigniter session value in localhost?

Tags: codeigniter, session

I am have install Two codeigniter develope two different different site in localhost.

issue is that any of site login after this session value config with anther value.

in two site for login i am create same session it;s name is user_login
when one of site login another side automatically login.

if logout one to site another site also logout.

so can you guide me how to setup and what are the change in config file to maintain session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you config file change the value of

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'you own name for the session'
```

and this will not occur again.
This is because both are using the same session name which is mention in the config file